# Anyone know how to upgrade rear backup camera on VW Routan or Chrysler Town & Country minivan (2009 model)?

Tags: chrysler, town-and-country, backup-camera

It's got really crappy video quality. So blurry and useless. Plus the backup camera does not come with guide lines so you cannot distance to object.

Has anyone upgraded it themselves with a new camera lens or new kit off eBay or other ideas?

Like to get some step-by-step photos of how to disassemble and assemble.

Comment: For step by step instructions on stuff like this, try searching 'car name' + forum, find one you like, then search 'that forum' + backup camera replacement, or something of the sort.